# Linear algebra for computer scientists

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm planning a linear algebra course for computer science freshmen. Do you have any good textbook to recommend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that [Linear Algebra Done Wrong by Sergei Treil](https://sites.google.com/a/brown.edu/sergei-treil-homepage/linear-algebra-done-wrong) is quite nice (of course, every book has its quirks).

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend Linear Algebra by Hoffman and Kunze. You can have a look [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-87D9cxiLfibzN1UTRkWTdHVFk/edit). It is probably more formal (it is for mathematicians) than needed for computer science, but if you are interested, you definitely benefit from it.

Comment: This book is theoretical. And useful for people doing Functional Analysis. Not recommended for people with specific applications in mind.